# is it secure for python use pickle file to store the username and password?

Tags: python, pickle

is it secure for python use pickle file to store the username and password?

I try to figure out what is the good practice to store the username and password in python? Can I just use pickle file?

Thanks!!

Comment: That's only for persistence, not encryption. Anyone who gets access to that file can just start Python and unpickle it.

Answer (score 3):

No. It's not secure to store username and password in pickle file.

Because a pickle file created on one computer can easily be read on another computer. Anyone who gets access to the file will be able to un-pickle it using the same pickle program you have used to pickle it.

You should ideally encode passwords using salt and secret key. There are [bcrypt](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bcrypt/3.1.1) libraries which do this.

Ideally you should not store passwords in files. Rather databases are a safer option. Also use standard libraries that automatically hash passwords using salts and store details in databases.

Make sure the database is password protected and system is secure using se-linux. What else?? Yeah, avoid storing passwords. Give google/Fb/Twitter login wherever possible. :)

Answer (score 3):

Providing examples to Vikash's excellent answer below.

[Secure Password Storage in Python](https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/02/how-safely-store-password-in-2016#python):

```
import bcrypt
import hmac
from getpass import getpass
master_secret_key = getpass('tell me the master secret key you are going to use')    
# Calculating a hash
hashed = bcrypt.hashpw(password, bcrypt.gensalt())
# Validating a hash (don't use ==)
if (hmac.compare_digest(bcrypt.hashpw(password, hashed), hashed)):
    # Login successful
```

Now that have the salt and hashed password, you need to store it somewhere on disk. Where ever you do store it, [you should set the file permissions to 600](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2868444/564514) (read/write by user only). If you plan on not allowing password changes, then 400 is better.

[Here's how you can do that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15015748/564514):

```
import os
import stat

# Define file params
fname = '/tmp/myfile'
flags = os.O_WRONLY | os.O_CREAT | os.O_EXCL  # Refer to "man 2 open".
mode = stat.S_IRUSR | stat.S_IWUSR  # This is 0o600 in octal and 384 in decimal.

# For security, remove file with potentially elevated mode
try:
    os.remove(fname)
except OSError:
    pass

# Open file descriptor
umask_original = os.umask(0)
try:
    fdesc = os.open(fname, flags, mode)
finally:
    os.umask(umask_original)

# Open file handle and write to file
with os.fdopen(fdesc, 'w') as fout:
    fout.write('something\n')
```

Comment: What's going on in this code? `master_secret_key` is read but unused, `password` is hashed twice… https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12042724/securely-storing-passwords-for-use-in-python-script has the proper implementation, but even better just use a credential store https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7014953/i-need-to-securely-store-a-username-and-password-in-python-what-are-my-options